# Query to find more wins than losses

Tags: sql, postgresql

uid refers to a unique user id and below are the numbers of matches they won / lost

matcheswon

```
uid wins
1   4
3   3
```

matches loss

```
uid losses
2   4
3   1
4   2
```

I want to determine the uid that have won more matches than they have lost. I'm unsure how to do this because some users that havent lost a match dont show up in the matches lost relation and same with wins

This is what I would do but wont show some

```
SELECT wins.uid
FROM Matcheswon w, matchesLost l
WHERE w.uid = l.uid AND w.wins > l.losses
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an outer join:

```
SELECT w.uid
FROM Matcheswon w LEFT JOIN
     matchesLost l
     ON w.uid = l.uid
WHERE w.wins > l.losses OR l.losses IS NULL;
```

This treats no rows in the losses table as `0` losses.